# How do I access a page instance from within a script on a master page?

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, livecycle, livecycle-designer

I have a button and script on a master page that is meant to remove the page when it is clicked.

But as far as I can see the script on the master page can only see the masterpage - it cannot see the page that is 'hosting' it.

Unless I can find the container that it is in, I cant call the instance mamger to remove it... Is this so? If not, how do I access the 'hosting' page?

This code on a button on the master page shows the 'problem', when used on a page and clicked, it shows the path for the master page field, not the page on which the button is hosted.

```
xfa.host.messageBox(this.somExpression);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your code, please?

Comment: Hi, I've added some code that shows my problem...

Comment: I don't think you can recognize this from the master page. So one way is calling the instance directly and the other way is putting the delete button inside a main page and let it be copied every time you add an instance.

Comment: thanks @Cold_Class - that is what I did.... moved the button onto the instance pages... bit disappointing, but there you go!

Comment: So, would you accept this as an official answer? :)

Comment: I don't know that it *isn't* possible, but if you post it as an solution/answer with that proviso, sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can recognize this from the master page. 
Communication between master- and normal pages always caused problems for me so I would not recommend trying it - there's usually always a less buggy way around it.
But one way is:

- calling the instance directly

and another way is:

- putting the delete button inside a main page and let it be copied every time you add an instance.